# SQL Convert Month and Week Number to date

Tags: sql, datetime

I know we can convert a date into a certain Week Number in SQL, can we do the reverse ? Eg :  I have Year, Month name and a week number like (2017,February,Week 2).

Can we convert this into the first date of the week starting Sunday ?
To give: 5-FEB-2017

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Week number in sql server is week number in the context of the year, not the month.

Comment: Week number is usually week in year, in both the WEEK() and the WEEK_ISO() functions.  Now February 2017 begins on a Wednesday. Is the first week: the one that starts on the 1st Sunday in the month?; the first week in the month that has more than 3 days(ISO)?; the part of a week before the first Sunday?

Comment: There is, in general, no such function in any DBMS that I would know, to sum it up. If I were you, I would create a calendar table for a few years, containing the date, then the year, the quarter, the month, the week_in_year, the week_in_month as you define them, the day of week, all as integers, and any other useful stuff - maybe month name, etc., and search that table whenever you need it.

Comment: @marcothesane: at least Postgres can do it, e.g. `to_date('2017-04', 'iyyy-iw')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select DATEADD(Day,weekNumber*7,[first day of month])